# regex with optional end of input

Tags: java, regex

Should be an easy one but I simply can't figure it out ...

Input will be like

> Starting text: 1 x A, 2 x B, 3 x C\noptionally more text

The "\n" only comes with the optional text and A, B, C can be anything of any length including dots and hyphens.

Result should be

> Starting text: 1 x A, 2 x B, 3 x C

My regex is

```
Starting text:( \d x .*?[,|\n|\$])+.*?
```

But that only works if the optional text with "\n" is present. Otherwise it returns

> Starting text: 1 x A, 2 x B,

How to get the "\$" working?

Comment: Note that `$` inside `[...]` is treated as a `$` char, not end of string. Use `(?:[,\n]|$)` to match a comma, newline or an end of string. Also, `.*?` at the end of pattern does not match any text, you may even delete it, or if you need that text after comma or newline, remove `?` there.

Comment: did you mean [`^(Starting text:.*?)\\n`](https://regex101.com/r/hhMjad/1)

Comment: Thank you both very much!

YCF_L reminded me that at this point I need everything up to the new line character / end of input for display. So no need to look for commas and details. And Wiktor showed how to make it work for both endings.

Resulting regex: (Starting text:.*?)(?:\\n|$)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(Starting\stext:[\d\w, ]+).*$
```

description

```
^         start of line
(         open subpattern
Starting  look for the word "Starting"
\s        look for one whitespace
text      look for the word "text"
:         look for doubledot
[\d\w,\s] look for numbers letters , or whitespace
+         one or more
)         close subpattern
.*        any characters
$         end of line
```